# sorting a file using the sort command and overwrite it

Tags: sort

i was trying to sort a text file and replace the sorted file with the original one, so i set the file to be also the output of the sort command too, but when i do that it clears the file contents and the file becomes empty, why? i can use another file to solve this problem but it doesn't feel nice :D, ( and i'm using Lubuntu. )

```
faav@faav-XPS-L501X:~$ cat test
A
C
B
faav@faav-XPS-L501X:~$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faav faav 6 Apr 14 00:28 test
faav@faav-XPS-L501X:~$ sort test > test
faav@faav-XPS-L501X:~$ cat test
faav@faav-XPS-L501X:~$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faav faav 0 Apr 14 00:28 test
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does redirection to the same file truncates the file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8414/why-does-redirection-to-the-same-file-truncates-the-file)

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/528658/redirect-pipe-output-to-the-same-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `-o` option of `sort` instead of using redirection operator, this will edit the file in place.

From [`man sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/sort.1posix.html):

```
-o, --output=FILE
              write result to FILE instead of standard output
```

Here is a test:

```bsh
$ cat test.txt 
A
C
B

$ sort test.txt 
A
B
C

$ sort test.txt -o test.txt

$ cat test.txt 
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the input / output file is truncated before its content is actually read, so `sort` ends up reading an already empty file.

In general (i.e. while redirecting the output of a command to its input file, since this issue doesn't only happen with `sort`), you can execute the required command within a subshell and store its output to a variable, then flush the content of the variable to the file (e.g. with `echo`), this way delaying the truncation of the input / output file to a point where the input file has been read already:

```
tmp=$(sort test) && echo "$tmp" >  test
```

Also note that this is not very efficient for large files, and that the `&&` operator has been chosen in place of `;` to avoid the truncation of the input / output file in case of a failure of the first command.

Comment: hey @kos  it didn't work, made the file emtpy...

Comment: You probably forget `;` or `&&` i.e. `tmp=$(sort test); echo "$tmp" >  test` ..also note that this is not efficient in case of a large file..

Comment: @favarjooy86 I forgot the `&&` operator to chain the commands, now it's fixed

Comment: can we use a pipe to do this? like `sort test.txt | echo > test.txt`

Comment: @knh190 This would truncate the file in first place because `echo` doesn't read from `stdin`, so even something like `echo "string" | echo > test.txt` would create an empty file. But even `sort test.txt | tee > test.txt` would suffer from the same problem, because within the same command the file would be always be truncated before it's actually read, despite the order of the commands within the pipe, that's how `bash` works. So the only way around is either to explicitly advance the read or to explicitly delay the write.

Answer (score -1):

You may write like **sort -b -o filename filename**, where filename specifies the same file twice as you want the output to be saved or overwrite to the original file.
This command works like, it shall remove any blank spaces and the sort the contents of file and overwrite to original file.

Then you can print the contents of file by mentioning **cat filename**, to print the contents of file as output on standard output device.

Thanks.

Comment: How is your answer differnt from the accepted answer?

Comment: Well i tried to through more light on how to use -o option and where ideally to place while writing down. Also tried to indicated importance of dealing with blank spaces which may cause wrong sorting order sometimes by showing use of -b. Hope it helps. Thanks